# Create React App throws error while starting server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

This error shows up whenever I run `npm start`.

I've tried `npm install`. I have no errors in the console.

Also I'm not using `JSON.parse` in any of my files.

Full error:

```
Starting the development server...

C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getBuildInfo (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107937:21)
    at readBuilderProgram (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120294:28)
    at Object.createWatchProgram (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120448:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:304:59)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Vito\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Vito\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:4:12)
    at Object.getIssues (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\repo\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin\lib\typescript-reporter\reporter\TypeScriptReporter.js:227:28)
```

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` to rebuild `node_modules` from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this steps

1. remove `node_modules`
2. intall again node packages `npm i`

Comment: yep ,This solved it .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the node modules. firstly delete the node modules folder

1.Delete node_modules folder.

2.open terminal and run --->   npm i

3.above command will install all the node modules again.